# How to merge two dataframes with pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

here are 2 dataframes :

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [19, 65, 7, 49, 66, 89, 545],
                  'b': [4, 6, 6, 90, 5, 77, 767],
                  'c': [34, 78, 65, 666, '', '', '']})

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [34, 78, 65, '', ''],
                  'd': [4, 6, 6, 90, 767]})
```

I would like to make a merge between them with "c" column as jointure.

In my case, I use this :

```
df = pd.merge(d1, d2, how='left')
```

But the result is not good. In fact, I have some doublons, plus the final result should be a dataframe with the same length of d1. In my case It is not true.

Here is the result I would like to have :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [19, 65, 7, 49, 66, 89, 545],
                  'b': [4, 6, 6, 90, 5, 77, 767],
                  'c': [34, 78, 65, 666, '', '', ''],
                  'd': [4, 6, 6, 90, 767, '', '']})
```

Comment: So, _how_ do you want to merge them? There are 5 ways of merging dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge

Comment: I want to join the two dataframe on "c" column without duplicate row

Comment: could you include your expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

use `concat()` and `fillna()`:

```
df=pd.concat([d1,d2.pop('d')],axis=1).fillna('')
#OR
df=pd.concat([d1,d2['d']],axis=1).fillna('')
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your expected output

Comment: It is not exactly the result I want. You can see it in the description

Comment: @ahmedaao why you are getting `867` at index `4` in your expected output?

Comment: sorry. Mistake It is 767

Comment: @ahmedaao Updated answer.....Kindly have a look ***:)***